# Fragment gets destroyed when I move back to a previous one using BottomNavigation and navigation architecture?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I a BottomNavigation which has some navigation on it. When I open the app I make some requests in the home fragment and when I move to another fragment by clicking the bottom navigation and then come back to the same fragment (home fragment) by clicking the bottom navigation it destroys my home fragment and recreates it again. But if I go back to the first fragment by back button it does not destroy my first fragment(home fragment)

Comment: Is your [Fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) still there? Any `ViewModel` you've attached to your Fragment, any state saved in `onSaveInstanceState`, etc. should all still be there. Is that the case for you?

Comment: But I mean how can I stop this behaviour of fragments, it is weird as we can reuse it no recreate it every time. Any idea on that ?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is your fragment's state being saved or not? Do you get a non-null `savedInstanceState` Bundle in your `onCreate()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is about choosing between `FragmentPagerAdapter` vs `FragmentStatepagerAdapter`. I suggest you to have a look [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/android-programming-the/9780134171517/ch11s02.html) and [this](https://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-fragmentpageradapter-vs-fragmentstatepageradapter/) articles.

Comment: To be honest I do not know how you ended in that conclusion. I think it is clear that it recreates the fragment every time I push bottom navigation (the icon of the fragment) and it does not save anything